# Can Sony SmartEyeglass perform live video and audio streaming?

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I am participating in a project which requires live video and audio streaming from the device to a computer. For this project, Sony SmartEyeglass is one candidate. Before acquiring the device, it is compulsory to check this requirement. I have already looked at the developer's website but it is not really clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, you don't know how providing a live stream works. 
Read about RTSP and RTMP.

I had good expriences with this nginx module:
https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module (this project is dead, but there is a fork by dailymotion). This worked great when using a USB webcam and a computer connected to an ethernet-Lan.

When I tried to stream data from my android device through wireless lan, the quality was very poor. If you want people to see great 720p/1080p/4k live streams with no delay - I don't think an android smart phone will be the best choice.

According to the sony api documentation, you can process the video input. So only perfomance should be a problem. Maybe you should first implement a solution based on an existing rtmp-app, then develop your own app and THEN try to integrate support for the Sony SmartEeyeglass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to stream from SmartEyeglass to a computer over the smartphone.

It can be achieved using JPEGStream API of the SmartEyeglass.

If you have any further questions, please do not hesitate to contact us over:
developer.world_at_sony.com (replace _ at_ with @)